# how to use gnu trove in eclipse

Tags: gnu, importerror, trove4j

I downloaded the gnu trove 3.03 and extract it to a local directory. then I add the `trove-3.03-src.jar` to my project in eclipse, but there is still import error like `The import gnu.trove.TDoubleArrayList cannot be resolved`,how can I solve this problem? Any reply will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not add just the "-src" jar file.  That jar file is for source code.  You need the binary jar.

Answer (score 0):

Just search for a .jar in the outmost folder and you should see 3 jars. 1. Junit.jar 2. trove-xxxx-src.jar and 3. trove-xxxx.jar Choose the one without SRC and import that.